# 64 bit variable read order (low and high) in 32 bit systems

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

In a 32-bit system, when trying to read a 64-bit variable, which bits will be read first? The high ones or the low ones? Or maybe it varies and we cant depend on it?
For instance:

`uint64_t counter = 4;
uint64_t foo = counter;`

So when the assignment to foo happens, counter will be read in 2 32-bit parts (low & high), which part is read first? low or high or does it vary?

Comment: What language are you considering here?  It looks like C/C++, but a language tag would help.

Comment: I didnt think language matters, yes its C/C++, I'll edit

Comment: The C standard doesn't say, and different hardware will do it differently.

Comment: Thanks @BoPersson, do you maybe have a link to where it says that?

Comment: Whatever it is is determined by the processor or the compiler. Not by the [tag:kernel].

Comment: Your question appears to be an **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) `uint64_t counter = 4; uint64_t foo = counter;` doesn't even provide a potential example of difference in Hi/Lo load order. What is it you are trying to do that would make any difference relevant?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The example was not meant to provide what im trying to do, only explain the question I need an answer to.
It doesnt really matter what im trying to do (its very long to explain).
Bottom line is, can I rely on some order when a 64-bit variable in being read in a 32-bit system? Like the lower 32-bit are always read before the higher ones, for example.

Comment: OK, I get the question, but is just seems like if you are not reading registers as they are filled on load in assembly, then it is somewhat of an esoteric question. As the answers provide -- it all depends on how your processor does it. You could break it down before that and talk about what bytes go through the data-bus first, but is all depends on your processor instruction set and what a load looks like for that hardware. You compiler has to coordinate the data in whatever manner it is used by your hardware.

Comment: If you're not familiar with [physical address extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), it's worth a read to understand what happens with 64bit addresses on a 32bit architecture ... To add to what @DavidC.Rankin was saying, even on a 64 bit machine, reading a `uint64_t` is system dependent as to which registers will get a load/store for which hi/lo values; so if you need determinism for your specific types, you'll have to implement that yourself or put a lock (like a mutex) around access to the variable.

Comment: Which 32 bits is fetched first from memory depends on if the architecture is `little Endian` or `big Endian`.   In any case, the lowest address bytes will be loaded first.  Followed by what instructions are generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is no rule for complers how to implement such operations. Also there is no such rule for hardware.

try this

```
   #include <iostream>

    using std::cout;

    union _64test {
        uint64_t _64;
        uint32_t _32[2];
    };

    int main() {

        _64test temp;
        temp._64 = 15;

        cout << temp._64 << "\n";
        cout << temp._32[0] <<" " << temp._32[1] << "\n";

        return 0;
    }
```

---

ouput :

15,

15 0

---

in my case, low part was 1st. due to union mechanics you can figure this out wherever you want

---

Comment: Thats just going to get me an answer regarding my specific system, I want to know how it is for all systems.

Comment: @tomer.z  As far as I remember there is no rule for complers how to implement such operations.

Comment: Some CPUs are big endian. Some are small.  All code has to work around it either way.

Comment: The question isn't about the logical order the bytes are stored in memory; it's about the temporal order of memory accesses.

Comment: Ah - missed that.  Thanks

Comment: Please note that your code invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) by reading from `temp._32` when you assigned to `temp._64`.

Answer (score 0):

> So when the assignment to foo happens, counter will be read in 2 32-bit parts (low & high), which part is read first? low or high or does it vary?

It can vary.

The C standard makes very few guarantees about the ordering of memory accesses in general, especially to variables that are not declared as `volatile`. It is possible that there won't even be two memory accesses, or that the memory accesses will be "split" (i.e, read one half, do something else, read the other half).

Comment: So basically its up to each processor to decide, but the programming language (C, in this example) can enforce an order but in our case (C) it doesnt?

Comment: It's up to the _compiler_ to decide, not the processor.

Comment: It is both compiler and, not processor but rather architecture. x86 and ARM handle these cases differently even with same compiler (GCC).

Comment: @GRC Right, I mean it's up to the compiler to decide **on a case-by-case basis**. It may not be consistent even on a specific compiler/architecture pair.

Comment: No, I am not confusing those two. Type `sizeof (long)` on x86 32 bit architecture and also on ARM. If I remember correctly some ARM architectures truncate it to 32 bits and some have 2 separate 32 bit chunks of memory.

Comment: @duskwuff Ok, I see your point!!!! We see world differently ;) You see it from a software side, I see it from hardware. I hope I did not piss you off.